# Firebase Cloud Messaging - invalidRegistration (php)

Tags: php, android, http, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have trouble with sending push notifications to topics in my Firebase project. If i run the php script, i gives me the error **'invalidRegistration'**

**php script:**

```
<?php


$topic = "/topics/info";
$fcm_server_url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

$title = utf8_encode("AleXoTroN");
$content_text = utf8_encode("AleXoTroN");
$color_code = utf8_encode("#2baa7f");


$httpheader = array('Content_Type:application/json', 'Authorization:key=***');
$msg = array('to' => $topic, 'data' => array('title' => $title, 'content_text' => $content_text, 'color' => $color_code));

$curl_connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_URL, $fcm_server_url);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpheader);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $msg);
$answerFromServer = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);

echo "Server:<br/>".$answerFromServer;

?>
```

And the code of the **FCM Instance ID** Service in my application;

```
public class FCM_IIDS extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    final String token_preference_key = "fcm_token";

    final static String infoTopicName = "info";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        super.onTokenRefresh();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(token_preference_key, FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()).apply();


        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(infoTopicName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't encoding to json your message.

Use [`json_encode($msg)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) before sending it to FCM.

Comment: So, according to docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref (Table 9)
`Check that the request contains a registration token (in the registration_id in a plain text message, or in the to or registration_ids field in JSON).`

Comment: but how do i get this token? and can i use it to send the notification to all devices which registered to my topic?

Comment: Are you tried before to send notification with firebase console to this channel?

Comment: Yes that works. I can send notifications with the notification ui at the console but my problem ist: If the app is in background or closed, firebase automaticly shows an pre-configurated notification which is not customizable. Thats because i want so send notifications with the script.

Comment: @AleXoTroN So use `notification` filed to send message that will be displayed to user.